# Calling a function from within that class - php

Tags: function, cakephp

I have a function called wsGO() inside a class ceff(). I want to be able to run that function from within the class ceff. I used this code:

```
class ceff{

    $ceff_instance = new ceff($this);
    $ceff_instance = wsGO();

    public function wsGO(){
        ....
    }
}
```

However this didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can only initialize a property with a constant - NOT functions or constructor calls. You can though do that in a constructor, such as:

```
class ceff{

   public $ceff_instance;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->ceff_instance = $this->wsGO();
   }

   public function wsGO(){
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: perfect!! however, my wsGO returns an array, how would I set that equal to a variable?